# NodeJs Botframework and Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, botframework

I've implemented a bot using botframework in node.js and typescript. I've installed `restify` package (as mentioned [here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/overview/)). Also, I want to use process through `NodeJS`. However, these are not found and detected in the program (as see in the following):

[image]

Therefore, my question is how can I use `restify` and `NodeJS` modules in typescript for botframework?

I should have mentioned that the npm hierarchy of the project likes the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a `tsconfig.json` file into the project such as the following:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true
    },
    "files": []
}
```

The point of the solution is `file` is empty. If just one file is added to the `files`, you must mention all other expected files to the list of the files in `files`. Respectively, if you do not mention any file in `files` all expected files are added by default.

### UPDATE

Another solution to this is deleting default Script Folder in the project. All the above issues come from this folder!

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a superset of javascript, so just rename your js files to .ts and you´re already using it.

So this example will look like this:

```
import * as builder from "botbuilder";
import * as restify from "restify";

// Setup Restify Server 
// prefer const or let instead of var
const server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
    console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat bot
const connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});

const bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector);
server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());

//=========================================================
// Bots Dialogs
//=========================================================

bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    session.send("Hello World");
});
```

Since process is a global variable in node, you may use [typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings) to add the autocomplete information...

Comment: I want to implement my bot in typescript, not in pure js! Please read my question exactly.

Comment: Try to save this as a .ts file and compile it to javascript - your bot should work without problems.  If your IDE permit (vs code is my default choice for typescript) you could hide all the .js and .js.map files...

Comment: My IDE is visual studio. Anyhow, I can't compile my ts files (it is my question)! how to generate a js file from the ts?!!

Comment: What Version? I have a VS2015 Ultimate - You should download the [typescript extension](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48593)

Comment: If you do not want to rely in Visual Studio to compile your files, you could install [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) to compile your files from the command line...

Comment: it's installed! my problem is after all of these. please read my question in more details!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139862/discussion-between-thiago-luiz-silva-and-omg).